# UISearchDisplayController search bar types letters automatically

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar, edit, uisearchdisplaycontroller

On editing the Search Bar in UISearchDisplayController, it repeats the first typed letter recursively until the second letter pressed.

Here is what happens:

[image]

Please suggest any possible solution.
Code:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString 
{
    [self filterContent:searchString scope:
    [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)SearchBar
{
    [SearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    SearchBar.text = @"";
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
-(void)filterContent:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope 
{
    _searchArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.user_name contains[c] %@", searchText], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.country_name contains[c] %@", searchText], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.city contains[c] %@", searchText], nil]];
   _searchArray = [_users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code of delegate functions of searchbar ?

Comment: are these the only delegates that you implement? It seems like you are doing something in searchBar:textDidChange: or searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: maybe ?

Comment: @WarrenBurton I have posted the complete delegates. Didn't use searchBar:textDidChange: or searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: Since I am using UISearchDisplayController delegate not UISearchBar delegates.

Answer (score 1):

@JananiM I think you having problem in this line [self filterContent:searchString...] which u assigned in your delegate method.

Try this one

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles][[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
```

}
 i have implemented your code (which you posted above) in my application.I didn't get anything like this.I have checked breakpoint too.Check this

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]